# Authors with same affiliations and one author with different affiliation

Tags: affiliation

I am want to make this format for my research paper. If anyone can help me with that would be great.[image]

Comment: This depends a lot on the specific class you use for your article. Can you share the `\documentclass` command at the start of your tex file?

Comment: \documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}

Comment: The `llncs` document class does not support this format for the institutions. You can see an example of the format in the documentation of the class, also available at https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/springer-lecture-notes-in-computer-science/kzwwpvhwnvfj (you may omit ORCID if you do not want them).